# Why does this 404 time out?

Tags: debugging, nginx, networking

Can someone explain why it can take a page 30 seconds to timeout? According to Chrome's debugger it is pending on a 404.

[image]

And that I don't get. If it is a 404, why doesn't it return page not found right away then?

The nginx config in question looks like this

```
# redirect http to https
server {
    listen ${API_PORT} default_server;
    listen [::]:${API_PORT} default_server;
    server_name example-api.${SITE_SUFFIX};
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  set $indexhtml 'index.html';

     # port to example on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
   listen 8443 ssl;

   # sets the domain[s] that this vhost server requests for
  server_name example.${SITE_SUFFIX};
  ssl_certificate     /certs/example.${SITE_SUFFIX}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /certs/example.${SITE_SUFFIX}/privkey.pem;
  proxy_ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;


  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  root /var/www/frontend/public;

  error_page 404 @404;

  include conf.d/sites/content.conf;

  # error page location redirect 302
  location @404 {
      return 302 /404;
  }
}

server {
  # port to example on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
  listen 8443 ssl;

   # sets the domain[s] that this vhost server requests for
  server_name sl.example.${SITE_SUFFIX};
  ssl_certificate     /certs/sl.example.${SITE_SUFFIX}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /certs/sl.example.${SITE_SUFFIX}/privkey.pem;
  proxy_ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;


  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  error_page 404 @404;

  include conf.d/sites/sh.conf;

  # error page location redirect 302
  location @404 {
      return 302 /404;
  }
}
```

**Update**

This is how it looks after the timeout.

[image]

Comment: The pending request is for a URI called `/404`, it's not a 404 status. The `error_page` invokes a `return 302 /404`, but it's not clear how the `/404` URI is being processed.

Comment: @RichardSmith The URL in the browser is `https://example.io/example/pages/01/test2.html` which becomes `https://example.io/404` after a long while. Does that help?

Comment: What does `https://example.io/404` return? Or does it just timeout after 30 seconds? As I said, it's unclear how you are processing `https://example.io/404`.

Comment: I now notice it redirects to `https://example.io:8443/404`. I wonder how the port redirect happens. I have updated the OP with a timeout screenshot, if that gives any clues.

Comment: Nginx forms a full URL by using the port that the `server` block is listen on. You can bypass this behaviour with `port_in_redirect off;` or using the full URL in the `return` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith Very nice! Could that be part of the problem, or is is in unrelated?

Comment: Quite possibly the problem. If port 8443 is inaccessible to the outside (as it should be), the connection will just timeout after about 30 seconds.